# Generating Unique API Resource Identifiers for a Composite Database Key

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a composite key in my database for a "room" entity, consisting of two fields: "room-id" and "building-id," where "building-id" serves as a foreign key. Both "room-id" and "building-id" are unique within this context.

Now, I'm looking for a way to generate a unique identifier for my API resource. Should I create a UUID and then convert it? And how should I handle changes to the composite key?

What would be the most suitable approach for achieving this?

Comment: There are **many** resources out there talking about this -- all great ideas/suggestions -- and yet, there's no consensus in the community about what's the *best* way to do it.

Comment: An example of such articles: https://vladmihalcea.com/uuid-database-primary-key/

Comment: Hello, the issue isn't about the design of the primary key (PK) itself. I already have a database with a composite PK in place. My challenge is to devise a suitable identifier for API resources that eliminates the need to use multiple keys to identify the entity.